# How to remove controls at runtime while navigating?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am going to create an online test for candidates. I have following requirements:

WHen I press next button controls like label of (Question #, QUestion text, Radio buttons with text should be cleared) and on pressing next button i want next records but at the sample place where first questions was with all its controls. How is it possible? If yes, please help me. Here is my code i have tried.
**dt is the datatable that i have been populated**

```
 protected void btnPrev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (increment > 0)
        {
            increment--;
            NavigateRecords();
        }                //tbFirst.Text = increment.ToString();
        else
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("First Record");
        }
    }



protected void btnLast_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        maxRows = dt.Rows.Count;
        if (increment != maxRows - 1)
        {
            // tbFirst.Text = increment.ToString();
            increment = maxRows - 1;
            NavigateRecords();
        }
    }                


protected void btnFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (increment > 0)
        {
            increment = 0;
            NavigateRecords();
        }                //tbFirst.Text = increment.ToString();

}


    protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)          
    {
        maxRows = dt.Rows.Count;
        if (increment != maxRows - 1)
        {
            increment++;

            NavigateRecords();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    public void NavigateRecords()
    {
        Page.Controls.Clear();
        dr = dt.Rows[increment];
        Label[] questionNo = new Label[dt.Rows.Count];
        Label[] questionText = new Label[dt.Rows.Count];
        RadioButton[] rbs = new RadioButton[dt.Rows.Count];

            //question no
            questionNo[increment] = new Label();
            questionNo[increment].Text = "<h3><div class=\"center-
           block\">Question: " + dt.Rows[increment]["SrNo"].ToString() + "</div></h3>";

            //question text
            questionText[increment] = new Label();
            questionText[increment].Text = "<h3>" + dt.Rows[increment]["QuestionText"].ToString() + "</h3>";
            divQuestionText.Controls.Add(questionNo[increment]);
            divQuestionText.Controls.Add(questionText[increment]);

            for (j = 3; j <= 6; j++)
            {
                rbs[increment] = new RadioButton();
                //option
                rbs[increment].GroupName = increment.ToString();
                rbs[increment].Text = dt.Rows[increment][j].ToString() + "<br>";
                divQuestionText.Controls.Add(rbs[increment]);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to create a own `Panel` for every step you have got. Then on `btnNext_Click`-Event you would have to either push the panel in the background or make it disapear using the `Control.Visible` attribute and bring the next one to the front.

This way you've got all the Controls you need editable with the "VS Form Inspector" and not have to mess with Control positions in code.

MfG

BMS

Comment: in next event i am doing this: divOnlineTest.Visible = false;
            foreach (Control item in divOnlineTest.Controls)
            {
                divOnlineTest.Controls.Remove(item);
            }
            if (i != maxRows - 1)
            {
                i++;

                NavigateRecords();
            }
but it gives me error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: I thought When pressing next button previous question's controls will be removed and next question data will be shown but it gave me error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Comment: You can not delete this with a `foreach` loop! E.g. You've got 4 Items now you delete the first (index 0). Foreach next trys to remove index 1 etc. but it see's that there was something different than before and stops. Try the `for`-loop (for does not use Enum's like foreach)